# How can I save results in list() of a nested for loop? [R]

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am trying to get a my_list<-list() or a vector<-c() out of this for-loop. It may be a simple but I can seem to get it.

```
seq<-seq(1,4,1)
```

```
for (p_try in seq_along(seq)){
  for (p_order  in seq_along(seq)){
    fmla<- paste("Rent ~ poly(SizeSqft,", p_order,") + poly(Bedrooms,",p_try,")")               
    assign(paste("R", p_order,p_try, sep = ""),as.formula(fmla))
  }}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save result in list() using append function

```
result <- list()

for (p_try in seq_along(seq)) {
  for (p_order  in seq_along(seq)) {
    fmla <- paste("Rent ~ poly(SizeSqft,", p_order,") + poly(Bedrooms,",p_try,")")
    result <- append(result, assign(paste("R", p_order,p_try, sep = ""),as.formula(fmla)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I was looking for (loop)!